# Коннект по ssh через 2 прокси-гейта в одну строку для ansible

Tags: ansible, ssh-tunnel

Нужно свести параметры подключения  водну строку для ansible - чтобы это было универсально.
Есть ssh конфиг для 2 гейтов:

## gate_1

`Host 10.20.30.40
  Hostname %h 
  User centos
  ForwardAgent yes
  ProxyCommand ssh user@111.222.333.444 -W %h:%p`

## gate_2

`Host 10.30.40.50
  Hostname %h 
  User centos
  ForwardAgent yes
  ProxyCommand ssh user2@222.333.444.555 -W %h:%p`

Как добавить в команду подключения для ansible - в строку подключения - второй гейт?

`ansible_ssh_user=centos
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@111.222.333.444"'`

Answer (score 3):

В свежих SSH клиентах есть `-J` для указания jump-host:

```
[myhosts]
host ansible_user=centos ansible_host=X.X.X.X ansible_ssh_common_args="-J user1@1.1.1.1,user2@2.2.2.2"
```

Comment: Вполне возможно, что вы правы! Но у меня не завелось. Видимо не слишком новый клиент)
`UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: unknown option -- J\r\nusage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]\n           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]\n}
`

Comment: Судя по релиз-ноутс поддерживается с `OpenSSH 7.2`.

Comment: у меня OpenSSH_7.2p2 - видимо нужен еще новее

Comment: @Dofri Думаю вы запускаете на Debian/Ubuntu в RHL/Fedora есть этот ключ у OpenSSH пакета